# Python Shiny form controls are not showing updated value

Tags: javascript, python

I have created an input_text() element through python shiny.
I am modifying the contents of the control through javascript (without actual user interaction with the input_text()) Even if i can see the updated data in the control inputctrlName gives the older data.
If I try to read the updated data from the said control, I am getting the updated data
if I interact with the control manually (even down arrow key works) then I am getting the updated data.

How can i read the updated  contents (by javascript) from the controls in shiny without interacting with the input_text()

PS: I want to hide the control so I am modifying the contents through javascript and then i am going to hide the control

I tried to simulate interactions through javascript with the help of dispatchEvent() but not working
I tried to remove the control and recreate the control through javascript but it is too not working